# Updating Robotium .jar file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, robotium

I have been using Robotium 3.3, but saw that a method has been added about a week ago, that will allow the user to input a name for any screenshots that are taken using `solo.takeScreenshot(String name)`, however, I'm not sure how to get this method to work. I have tried to download the updated file from github, then create a java project with the downloaded file, then export that project to a .jar file, but I am not having any luck getting that method to work. Here is a link to the method I'm talking about. If anyone could offer any help or direction, that would be great!

Link: https://github.com/jayway/robotium/blob/master/robotium-solo/src/main/java/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo/Solo.java

Answer (score 2):

i am using robotium-solo-3.4.1.jar

[image: add robotium jar reference]

i use this code :

```
int i=1;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

solo.takeScreenshot(currentDateandTime+"_1"+i);
```

and i get images like this, [ /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/05092012180241_1.jpg ]

[image]

i hope this will help you.
Thanks.